# Adding class to a div on different page by following the URL

Tags: jquery, anchor

I have some anchor links on my home page. On another page, I have some toggle section. I am trying to achieve functionality if I click on an item on the home page it will follow the link and add a class to a specific div on that page. Here is what I tried but not working

```
     $("#home_pro a").each(function(){
        var ThisHref = ($(this).attr('href').split('?'))[0];
        if(window.location.href == ThisHref) {
            $('.item1 .elementor-tab-title, .item1 .elementor-tab-content').addClass('active');
        }
   });
```

Answer (score 0):

you can only add a class to a new page *After* it has loaded. So have a document ready ( `$(function(){})` ) in that page and read in the url query (the part after ? in the url) with `window.location.search` and add your class accordingly. Alternatively you could send a session or cookie...

for example consider this url: `mysite.com/login.php?activated` then in the page login.php your script could look like:

```
$(function(){
  query=window.location.search;
  if (query =='activated'){
     $('.item1 .elementor-tab-title, .item1 .elementor-tab-content').addClass('active');
  }
})
```